# API errors on Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

I created a POST function to Harvest using postman and it was successful, I exported the code in as javascript but then when I go to run it in the google apps script I get, ‘ReferenceError: “FormData” is not defined.’

Any idea what this is referring too?

```
function myFunction() {

var data = new FormData();
data.append(“name”, “TEST_CLIENT”);
data.append(“is_active”, “true”);
data.append(“address”, “”);
data.append(“currency”, “USD”);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener(“readystatechange”, function () {
if (this.readyState === 4) {
console.log(this.responseText);
}
});

xhr.open(“POST”, “https://api.harvestapp.com/v2/clients? 
name=TEST_CLIENT&is_active=true&address=1%20Main%20st.%20&currency=USD”);
xhr.setRequestHeader(“Authorization”, “Bearer {{$ACCESS_TOKEN}}”);
xhr.setRequestHeader(“Harvest-Account-Id”, “{{$ACCOUNT_ID}}”);
xhr.setRequestHeader(“User-Agent”, “(hidden)”);
xhr.setRequestHeader(“Content-Type”, “application/x-www-form-urlencoded”);
xhr.setRequestHeader(“Cache-Control”, “no-cache”);
xhr.setRequestHeader(“Postman-Token”, “HIDDEN”);

xhr.send(data);
}
```

I hid some parts of my code

Comment: Where did you put `FormData` usage? There is definitely no such class on Apps Script/App Maker server side as well as XMLHttpRequest. If you are using client script, check out browser compatibility here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Comment: Please consider editing your question's name to be more descriptive.

Comment: Would be be a better practice to use jquery ajax?

Comment: You want to use your script in your question at Google Apps Script. If my understanding is correct, how about checking about [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)? Because your script is Javascript, but it is not Google Apps Script.